# Oracle check constraint with column name only?

Tags: oracle

I read the following Oracle DDL.

```
create table TName (
    -- ....
    ColX number(38, 0),
    ColY timestamp,

    constraint C1 check (ColX),
    constraint C2 check (ColY)
)
```

What's the constraints which have only column name?

Answer (score 1):

Which constraint? Looks like an *invalid* constraint.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (colx number,
  3     constraint c1 check (colx)
  4    );
   constraint c1 check (colx)
                            *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator


SQL>
```

In other words, that's wrong syntax. Where did you read it? Is it related to Oracle?

Comment: It's a problem of the tool (DBeaver) scripting. It generates incomplete SQL.